# Javascript templating - which uses #{variable} syntax

Tags: javascript, template-engine

Hi I'm looking for a good javascript templating engine that I can use this syntax.

```
#{interpolation here}

<li>#{label}</li>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
many thanks

Comment: Did you end up with this syntax because you used a specific templating script in the past?

Comment: No idea - just gotta use some fragments that are being used server side. I guess the templating solution server side is using that syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template) templating. Underscore contains a lot of other utility functionality you might find helpful.

```
// sets templating to "#{}" pattern
_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate : /#\{(.+?)\}/g
};

var template = _.template("Hello #{name}!");
template({name : "Chin"}); // "Hello Chin!"
```

Code to play with is [here](http://jsbin.com/ogocaw/edit#javascript,live).

Comment: thanks, that's great - so happens underscore is already on the page. before I plunge in, any drawback to underscore you can mention.

Comment: @Chin The only draw back is that it returns compiled HTML so you have to faff around with `innerHTML`. You might want to wrap it so it returns a documentfragment instead.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you checkout Underscore's template function: http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template

By default it uses other chars for interpolation, but they are customizable so you will have no problems in changing them

Edit: It seems nettuts just posted an article (+video) on how to create a template with JavaScript, it's really good: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-a-makeshift-javascript-templating-solution/

Comment: thanks - just looking at it now. Uses <%= - out of interest is this the same as ejs, I keep coming across? Also, have you ever used jade on the client side? That also interests me.

Comment: @Chin you can customize the settings, see my answer for a code example

Comment: No problem, if you want to make a template yourself, checkout John Resig's tutorial here: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [JsRender](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/index.html)

> Next-generation jQuery Templates, optimized for high-performance pure string-based rendering, without DOM or jQuery dependency

Or if your prefer something based on jQuery, you can use [jquery template](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/).

Comment: Where is the documentation for that script? Are we supposed to look at the source code for each sample... ?

Comment: thanks, for reasons beyond my control - It needs to be the syntax above. JsRender looks good but uses - {{=label}}

Comment: Yes the source is the place to look in [step-by-step pages](http://borismoore.github.com/jsviews/demos/step-by-step/index.html)

Comment: @StéphaneBebrone That's not very user-friendly. The author should definitively make a "Getting started" page.

Comment: In this case maybe the best would be to fork sources and create a customized version that fits your scenario.

Comment: jQuery templates is deprecated. It should not be recommended

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Tempo:

http://tempojs.com/

The notation is like this:

```
<ol id="tweets">
    <li data-template>
        <img src="default.png" data-src="{{profile_image_url}}" />
        <h3>{{from_user}}</h3>
        <p>{{text}}<span>, {{created_at|date 'HH:mm on EEEE'}}</span></p>
    </li>
    <li data-template-fallback>Sorry, JavaScript required!</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: How's that different from mustache? :\

Comment: I'm sorry, I knew nothing about mustache until you mention it. I did a quick search about it and they really are very alike.